# Cannot read property '_header' of undefined in finalHandler node module

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I can't seem to find a solution to my problem. I am trying to startup my nodeJS/expressJS app but am receiving an error upon "npm start".

**The Error & Stacktrace:**

```
    /Users/jmccreary/Documents/NewHireSite/node_modules/finalhandler/index.js:94
    if (!err && res._header) {
                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '_header' of undefined
    at /Users/jmccreary/Documents/NewHireSite/node_modules/finalhandler/index.js:94:20
    at /Users/jmccreary/Documents/NewHireSite/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15
    at next (/Users/jmccreary/Documents/NewHireSite/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:210:14)
    at Function.handle (/Users/jmccreary/Documents/NewHireSite/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at Function.handle (/Users/jmccreary/Documents/NewHireSite/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:174:10)
    at app (/Users/jmccreary/Documents/NewHireSite/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:38:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jmccreary/Documents/NewHireSite/app.js:101:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jmccreary/Documents/NewHireSite/bin/www:7:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:427:7)
```

**The Offending Code (in node_modules/finalhandler/index.js):

(Note: I added the console.logs myself, they are not part of the module)**

```
  function finalhandler (req, res, options) {
  var opts = options || {}
  console.log("The req is: ", req);
  console.log("The res is: ", res);

  // get environment
  var env = opts.env || process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'

  // get error callback
  var onerror = opts.onerror

  return function (err) {
    var headers
    var msg
    var status

    // ignore 404 on in-flight response
    if (!err && res._header) {
      debug('cannot 404 after headers sent')
      return
    }
    ...
```

**From my console.log()'s as shown, the output is below:**

```
 The req is:  Authenticator {
  _key: 'passport',
  _strategies: { session: SessionStrategy { name: 'session' } },
  _serializers: [],
  _deserializers: [],
  _infoTransformers: [],
  _framework: 
   { initialize: [Function: initialize],
     authenticate: [Function: authenticate] },
  _userProperty: 'user',
  Authenticator: [Function: Authenticator],
  Passport: [Function: Authenticator],
  Strategy: { [Function: Strategy] Strategy: [Circular] },
  strategies: { SessionStrategy: { [Function: SessionStrategy] super_: [Object] } } }
 The res is:  undefined
```

**EDIT**: This is, what I believe, is the code calling the error (from node_modules/express/lib/application.js):

```
 /**
 * Dispatch a req, res pair into the application. Starts pipeline processing.
 *
 * If no callback is provided, then default error handlers will respond
 * in the event of an error bubbling through the stack.
 *
 * @private
 */

app.handle = function handle(req, res, callback) {
  var router = this._router;

  // final handler
  var done = callback || finalhandler(req, res, {
    env: this.get('env'),
    onerror: logerror.bind(this)
  });

  // no routes
  if (!router) {
    debug('no routes defined on app');
    done();
    return;
  }

  router.handle(req, res, done);
};
```

My package.json file (using Express 4) is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "newhiresite",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.17.1",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.3",
    "express": "~4.15.2",
    "express-session": "^1.15.3",
    "express-validator": "^3.2.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.25",
    "mongoose": "^4.10.1",
    "morgan": "~1.8.1",
    "node-sass-middleware": "0.9.8",
    "passport": "~0.3.2",
    "passport-local": "~1.0.0",
    "pug": "~2.0.0-rc.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

I am able to run the tutorial's source code just fine, and it has the same modules as my app, which is nearly identical (except for a www/bin file upon npm start command). I've tried removing other modules and moving things around in my app.js file to no avail.

Any pointers or help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The most important part is missing: the code in which you use `finalhandler`.

Comment: I believe I added the correct code. This is my first nodeJS app so if that is not correct then please let me know what you believe might be calling it.

Comment: Somewhere in your code you're calling `finalhandler(...)`. You should post that code.

Comment: So apparently, its being called from the express node module. I added the call from that module as well as my package.json file. My express version is 4.15.2. The most up-to-date is 4.15.3, but even after specifying 4.15.3 and running npm install then npm start, the error remains.

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought that you were using it yourself. Anyway, the stack trace points to `app.js` line 101 as a potential location of the cause. Also, I'm not sure if I understand the `console.log` output that you're showing (starting with `The req is: Authenticator`). It seems you're logging from inside a Passport handler or something?

Comment: Just had this exact same problem, made a typo with `const express = require('express')(); const app = express();`, when it should be `const express = require('express');`

Comment: I believe I fixed my issue, but I changed many things as I had underlying issues as well. I had to pass my passport variable into my config file before I established my routes. Perhaps, then, that is why the finalHandler did not have a response, because the app was getting hung up on not knowing what passport is (although the error message was not very clear, and apparently it is thrown when a variety of user errors are made).

Comment: I get solution by call it `require('express-session')`

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error. The following solved the problem for me, maybe it does for you? I had this code:

```
var express = require('express')();
var app = express();

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s');
});
```

It has a () too many. Removing it solved the problem:

```
var express = require('express');
```

Comment: `()` How you think it related answer with this Question?
Nothing I get help from your Answer.

Comment: This might not help with the original question, but in my case, I have the extra () as well and that's what's causing my issue. Totally missed that one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem just moment ago. It all started to happen when I started cleaning code, like removing";" at the end of the lines. I bring back one of these ";" and problem disappeared.